# How to push to another view on DatePicker Selection changes on SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I have a SwiftUI `DatePicker` and i need to push to another view on date selection.

I tried a `NavigationLink` on `DatePicker` and `DatePicker.OnChange` modifier but no luck.

any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: You better improve your question to have more focus on it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```swift
   struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selectedDate = Date()
    @State var navigationActive = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                DatePicker("Select date", selection: $selectedDate)
                    .onChange(of: selectedDate, perform: { value in
                        print(selectedDate)
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) { //this is because, otherwise user will not see the date selection on date picker
                            navigationActive = true
                        }
                        
                })
                NavigationLink("", destination: Text("Destination"), isActive: $navigationActive)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: using ZStack instead of VStack should hide NavigationLink arrow at the bottom of the datepicker